# Iterating through a generic list of Objects and printing the values

Tags: c#, list

I would like to have a utility function which reads the values in a generic List of objects and prints them like the example below(please refer to the comments in the code). I am able to get the property names like RowIndex,BookingId etc in my output but not sure how to get the values assigned to those properties. At run time I have no idea about the object properties(names) So for example lets say. Can some one please help me.

```
public class ReadList
{
    public void ReadList<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        try
        {                              
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                Type myObject = list[i].GetType();
                List<string> propertyInfo = myObject.GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();                    
                foreach (var propName in propertyInfo)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Property Name : " + propName);
                }
                //How to get  access to the property values?
                //For example How can I access the Property names and values and print them on the screen like below
                //Property Name : RowIndex , Property Value : 1      
                //Property Name : RowIndex , Property Value : 2
                //Property Name : RowIndex , Property Value : 3
                //Property Name : RowIndex , Property Value : 4                  
            }               
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            //throw;
        }
    }
    public void Read()
    {
        List<RecurringBookingDetails> list = new List<RecurringBookingDetails>();
        list.Add(new RecurringBookingDetails() { RowIndex = 1 });
        list.Add(new RecurringBookingDetails() { RowIndex = 2 });
        list.Add(new RecurringBookingDetails() { RowIndex = 3 });
        list.Add(new RecurringBookingDetails() { RowIndex = 4 });
        ReadList(list);

        List<CasualBookingDetails> list2 = new List<CasualBookingDetails>();
        list2.Add(new CasualBookingDetails() { BookingID = 1 ,BookingName="A"});
        list2.Add(new CasualBookingDetails() { BookingID = 2 ,BookingName="B"});
        list2.Add(new CasualBookingDetails() { BookingID = 3 ,BookingName="C"});
        list2.Add(new CasualBookingDetails() { BookingID = 4 ,BookingName="D"});
        ReadList(list2);
    }
}

public class RecurringBookingDetails
{       
    public int RowIndex { get; set; }
}

public class CasualBookingDetails
{       
    public int BookingID { get; set; }
    public int BookingName{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Maybe Reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to immediately mapped all the `PropertyInfo`s to their names after calling `GetProperties`. Now you don't have `PropertyInfo` objects anymore, which you need, to get the properties' values. You need to call [`PropertyInfo.GetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public void ReadList<T>(List<T> list) {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
            Type myObject = list[i].GetType();
            // just get the array of properties without "Select"
            var propertyInfo = myObject.GetProperties();
            foreach (var prop in propertyInfo) {
                Console.WriteLine("Property Name : " + prop.Name);
                // Here you can call "GetValue", with the object being "list[i]"
                Console.WriteLine("Property Value : " + prop.GetValue(list[i]));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        //throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sweeper,its working and thanks for explaining the usage of GetValue method.Your comments were very useful.